# Why a @GetMapping annotated method is returning a JSON object between square brackets as response and how to fix it?

Tags: java, json, spring

I have a service with the following method:

```
@RestController
public class BillsController {
...
    @GetMapping("get/billById/{billId}")
    Mono<BillDto> getBillById(@PathVariable Long billId) {
        log.info("Request received to fetch Bill with id : " + billId);
        return Mono.just(service.getBillById(billId));
    }
...
}
```

And it returns the following:

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "customer": "Larry",
        "products": [
            {
                "id": 5,
                "name": "Bike"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Why would a JSON object between square brackets be returned? Since the `service.getBillById()` method returns just one object.

The `service.getBillById()` just maps the response from the declarative BillRepository into the BillDto class.

```
public BillDto getBillById(Long billId) {
    return modelMapper.map(billRepository.findById(billId).orElseThrow(NullPointerException::new), BillDto.class);
}
```

I´m getting the following error by the time I consume the response within a Client:

> reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: org.springframework.core.codec.DecodingException: JSON decoding error: Cannot deserialize value of type `library.dto.BillDto` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `library.dto.BillDto` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)

The client-side code:

```
Mono<BillDto> billDtoMono = client.getBilById(bill.getId());
billDtoMono.subscribe(BillDto -> {
    log.info(BillDto.toString());
});
```

Let's just say that if I invoke the `subscribe()` method within the `@GetMapping` method, it works just fine, how could I make the response well-formed when it goes outside?

Comment: Can you double-check the JSON you posted is the one you find in the response body of that `getBillById` method? I believe you mixed stuff, because that code won't return an array indeed. Unless `BillDto` is a subclass of `Collection`, but this would be rather convoluted :)

Comment: Ramiro, could you include the service code also?

Comment: I am sure that is the response I´m getting both on Postman and I can tell my Client too because of the exception I´m getting. BillDto is just a @Data annotated class with the attributes of the bills. If I run Mono.just().subscribe inside the endpoint method before returning the response I get no exception.

Comment: @JamesWagstaff Code added good man.

Comment: Stupid Idea: are you sure your id is a unique Key in your schema définition ? If not, you get an array.

Comment: So looking at this, I would be looking at checking the model mapper.

Comment: Why? Because you don't "get a JSON object", but a "reactive, non-blocking, json object emitter" ;)

Comment: Is there any thechnical problem connected to the format? (Or "just esthetics"/human?) ..Do you need Mono as a result wrapper?/is billdto not just fine ?(and without brackets!?)

Comment: @xerx593 you are right, I could easily map the result of the response into a BillDto[].class and problem solved, it´s just that I intended to do it as orthodox as possible